# MongoDB, Mongoose find all where _id is equal to key of object in array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Struggling with a query, I have a collection of users:

```
{
    "_id": "5c87bda25fdaasdf00171001e1",
    "name": "UserTwo Name",
    "email": "email2@example.com"
},{
    "_id": "5c87bda25fda8b00171001e1",
    "name": "User Name",
    "email": "email@example.com"
}
```

I also have an array of objects containing a _userId key. I need to get all users where the _id of the user equals the value of _userId in my array.

```
[
    {_userId: "5c87bda25fda8b00171001e1"},
    {_userId: "5c87bda25fdaasdf00171001e1"},
]
```

What I have so far is:

```
User.find(
        {
            _id: { $in: req.body.users }
        }
    )
```

Which should be fine if req.body.users was just an array of ids, not array of objects.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should modify your query like this:

```
 User.find({
            _id: { $in: req.body.users.map(user => ObjectId(user._userId) }
 });
```

You need to convert _userId string to ObjectId. And that will be done with `map` function.

Comment: Spot on, thanks! Wasn't aware you could use JS methods directly within the query.

Answer (score 0):

You have to turn the array

```
[
    {_userId: "5c87bda25fda8b00171001e1"},
    {_userId: "5c87bda25fdaasdf00171001e1"},
]
```

into

```
[
    "5c87bda25fda8b00171001e1",
    "5c87bda25fdaasdf00171001e1",
]
```

So how can we do that ?

---

**Example 1** : using `Array.map` which iterate through the specified array, call a function and then create a new array with values being the ones returned by the function it called.

```js
console.log([{
  _userId: "5c87bda25fda8b00171001e1",
},
{
  _userId: "5c87bda25fdaasdf00171001e1",
},
].map(x => x._userId));
```

---

**Example 2** : Using a well known `for` loop and create the array ourselves

```js
const arr = [{
  _userId: "5c87bda25fda8b00171001e1"
}, {
  _userId: "5c87bda25fdasdf0017101e1"
}, ];

const newArr = [];

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 1) {
  newArr.push(arr[i]._userId);
}

console.log(newArr);
```

---

**PS** : As @Ivan Vasiljevic proposed, when building the array of id, you can turn the `string` into `ObjectID` objects. It's not mandatory to do it using `mongoose.find` ; it is tho using `mongoose.aggregate`.

Comment: Hi, I am aware I could map the array and return a one dimensional array of strings, I am trying to avoid that by handling this in a query. I want to avoid mutating any formatted data within the client. Thanks anyway, sorted now

Comment: @MLWDEV This is exacly the same answer as @Ivan Vasiljevic, just that it does use the return of the `map` function directly in the json that's used for the query instead of putting it in a variable and use it later. This ->  ** I want to avoid mutating any formatted data within the client.** is totally wrong, we both are not mutating the original object.

Comment: I must admit that @GrégoryNEUT is correct. Mutation that my code is doing is also done on client. So before command is sent to MongoDB, map function is executed on client.

Comment: I thought you were referring to sending the data to the API that way. I just meant I want to do this on the server, I know that what Ivan suggested is just creating a one dimensional array to perform the check.